# Move code from Fragments into MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 5 Fragments with basically the same code except for the onCreateLoader override. Is there a way to move the code that all my fragments share inside the Main Activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `BaseFragment` which will contain your common code. After that extend your fragments from `BaseFragment` like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment
```

Comment: Worked nice. I had to change all my methods and variables to public so that they can be accessed but it worked like a charm. Thanks.